# Jplayer not playing in firefox despite all efforts

Tags: zend-framework, jplayer

Hi Guys I have tried practically everything on this question and tried every solution on this forum and still unable to figure out the solution for this problem. I am unable to play mp3 files from Jplayer despite giving correct swf path. Files are playing in chrome and IE but not firefox

```
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3:"<?php echo Zend_Registry::getInstance()->constants->img_profilepath .       $this->acc->Username . '/' . Zend_Registry::getInstance()->constants->img_albumpath . '/' . $this->album->Id . '/' . Zend_Registry::getInstance()->constants->audio_path . '/' . $this->playsong->Id . $this->playsong->Audio; ?>"
        }).jPlayer("play");
    },
    swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/Jplayer.swf",
    solution:"html,flash",
    supplied: "mp3",
    cssSelectorAncestor: ""


});
document.getElementById("track-title").innerHTML='<h6 class="subheader"><marquee><?php     echo$this->playsong->Title;?></marquee></h6>';

 });
 </script>
```

And this is the script that is executed when media is played

```
function play(url,title,songid)
{

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("setMedia", 
    { 
    mp3: url

    }); 
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer("play", 0);
document.getElementById("track-title").innerHTML='<h6 class="subheader"><marquee>'+title+'</marquee></h6>';


$.post('/audioplayer/played',
    {'songid' : songid});

    }
}
```

Comment: Are there any javascript errors?

Answer (score 0):

Note the following line:

```
swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/Jplayer.swf",
```

I've seen people do this before and it was problematic.  This is what I suggest

- Download the swf file
- Place it in the directory where you have your javascript for jPlayer
- change the swfPath to point to that location - without specifying the name of the swf file

So, for example, lets say you have a directory like /js/jplayer - download the swf into there... then change your code:

```
swfPath: "/js/jplayer"
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys the disqus plugin was causing the problem. When I removed it player started working fine. Thanks once again